# python "r+" requires file to exist?

Tags: python, file

I know that it doesn't make sense to open file for reading if it doesn't exist, unlike for writing. But I need to create a file object, write data to it and then read it later, that's why I want to use the "r+" mode. Of course I can just open the file for writing once and then open the saved file for reading, but the problem is I don't want the file to be saved to disc. Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't want the file to be saved to disc then why are you opening it at all?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should be using a [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) then. It imitates file-like operations (such as writing to and reading from it).

Comment: but I might need to write the file in the end, based on some checks. Hm, maybe I should just change the desing to work on strings

Comment: @martini - If you realise you want to write the file at the end, you could simply copy the content of the StringIO object to a physical file.